# Qualtrics scoring Loop & Merge questions

Tags: javascript, loops, merge, qualtrics, scoring

I'm setting up a simple Qualtrics survey with one question with a Loop & Merge function (in this one block); in Loop & Merge field 1, I've provided the URLs to my media files. The respondents have to select the right answer from two answer options (let's say Yes/No). All all my files are set up as a Loop & Merge within **one** question so that I won't have to create 100 separate questions for each individual media file.

This works great, however, I would also like to score my respondents' answers. The regular "scoring" feature in Qualtrics doesn't seem to work for me, since I can only provide **one** scoring option per question (i.e. I could only say that the first answer is always 1 point, and the second answer is always 0 points). However, the correct answer varies between my files (sometimes it's Yes/the first option; sometimes it's No/the second option).

I'm thinking there might be a way to list the correct answer (=i.e. the answer that should receive 1 point) in Field 2 in the Loop & Merge function; and then include some (javascript?) code in the question which would check the survey taker's answer choice against the "correct answer" in Field 2 of the Loop & Merge function for each media file. The code would assign "1" point if the participant's selected answer corresponds to Field 2 for each media file.

How would I write the (javascript) code to calculate a score for each question and an overall score at the end? (I don't need survey takers to see their score, but once a person is done, I would like to quickly see what their final overall score is, say 72 out of 100 possible points.)

Update: In the loop/merge function, I've added the right answer (for each file) in Field2, the incorrect answer in Field3. As suggested below, I've piped loop fields (2 and 3) into my question choices. I've added code in Field4 about whether or not the order of the answer options should be changed (0,1; 0= don't change order, 1= change order) so that the options always occur in the same order (for example, always Choice 1 = "Yes", Choice 2 = "No".) I've (unsuccessfully) tried to use the following JS code to refer to Field 4:

```
if (${lm://Field/4}==1) {
    (choiceNum = ${lm://Field/3},  ${lm://Field/2})
}
```

If there is a way to work without JavaScript, I'd be glad to hear about that option as well.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Fields piped into JavaScript always have to be in quotes, then compared to a string (unless you convert them to a number). The 'choicenum' line doesn't make any sense and isn't even valid JS.  You need to find and move the correct html element. Hint: Go to http://api.prototypejs.org/ and look up down and insert.

Answer (score 0):

How about this without JavaScript:

- Include your two choices as loop fields: Field 2 is correct answer, Field 3 is incorrect answer
- Pipe your loop fields (2 and 3) into your question choices
- Randomize the choices
- Score the question: Choice 1/Field 2 = 1 point, Choice 2/Field 3 = 0 points.

Comment: Hi T. Gibbons,

Thank you so much for your answer! I tried this out, and this works great and does the trick. Many thanks!

In my case, however, I would like to keep the ordering of the answer options the same ("Yes"/"No") for all questions, if at all possible, just so that people don't have to double check the order of the options before answering. 

Would it be possible to do something similar but in such a way that the answer options always occur in the same sequence? For example, always:
 
Choice 1 = "Yes"
Choice 2 = "No"

Thank you so much!

Comment: No, to do the scoring the correct answer has to always be in the same position (e.g., first), then it is randomized so it isn't always in the first position for respondents. You'd have to go the JavaScript route to keep Yes/No in order. You'd turn off randomization, and have a third loop/merge field that the JavaScript would use to know whether or not to reverse the choice order.

Comment: That isn't how StackOverflow works. It is for programmers to help each other. It isn't a free programming service. Since you are new to JavaScript this is a good opportunity to learn. If you get stuck, edit your OP and add your code.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. I've turned off randomization on the presentation of answer choice options and have added a Field3 in the loop/merge field (0,1; 0= don't change order, 1= change order).     I've (unsuccessfully) tried to use the following JS code:                                                                                                             {
 if (${lm://Field/3}==1) {
  (choiceNum = ${lm://Field/2}, ${lm://Field/1})
 }
});   Since I'm new to JavaScript, would someone be able to suggest modifications I could try? (I understand if not if my code is too far off.)

Comment: Add your code to your original post/question above.